# Segmentation fault when zip 2 self-defined type list

Tags: haskell

Under GHCi 7.10.2 on a [Parallella](https://www.parallella.org/), I defined a data type `Peg` which derives `Show`. 
I got a segmentation fault when I tried to zip two `Peg` lists. 
Does anyone have any clues?

```
sid@linaro-nano:~CIS192/hw_2$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude>
Prelude>
Prelude> data Peg = Red | Green deriving (Show)
Prelude> zip [Red, Red] [Green, Green]
[(Red,Green),(Segmentation fault
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Maybe you GHCi installation does not work properly? Can you run other programs in GHCi without crashes? E.g. `zip [1,2] [3,4]` ? In Haskell, unless you're working with very low-level stuff, there's no way to cause a segfault. Something looks wrong in your GHCi, therefore.

Comment: Yes, zip [1,2] [3,4] is ok.

Comment: It gets seg fault only when defines a type which deriving Show.

Comment: It works fine on my Mac, but it does not work on my Parallella. I guess something wrong with my Parallella.

Comment: I would run a memory test.

Comment: For what it's worth: I will not be voting to close this question. The question is clearly described, and obviously a problem. Is it an unusual problem? Absolutely! Is it actually a problem with Sid's understanding of Haskell? Nope. But is there a chance this will be helpful to somebody searching for "segmentation fault [haskell]" at some point in the future? I think so. I also don't think the current front-runner ("a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error") describes this problem -- presumably it is at least intermittently reproducible, and it's not a typo.

Comment: @DanielWagner, it would be really nice to get a sense of whether this occurs consistently on the Parallella platform! If so, then this is a bug (in something) that needs to be fixed, and the question is useful for future searchers. If not, then it's a one-off issue with one board, and the question is not useful. I wouldn't personally vote to close as yet.

Comment: This looks like https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10375.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Reid Barton's comment:

There was [a serious bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10375) with GHC's support for ARM CPUs, related to ARM having two different instruction set modes (Arm and Thumb).  The GCC-compiled runtime system and LLVM compiled library/user code used different default choices.  GHCi's runtime linker didn't understand those properly, causing crashes when jumping from code written in one mode to code written in the other.

The bug has just been fixed (by essentially forcing Arm mode everywhere), and the fix should be in the upcoming GHC 7.10.3 and 8.0.1 releases.

Comment: Sounds like yet another good reason to actually get a 7.10.3 release.